# Ruby array of countries stripe connect accepts?

Tags: ruby, stripe-payments

Is there somewhere I can get this list of countries as a ruby array?

[image]

I'll need it for a form field e.g.

```
<%= f.label :country %><br>
<%= f.select :country, ['Australia', 'Austria', 'etc', 'etc'], required: true %>
```

I could type it up manually (which I'll probably do), but just wanted to check that I'm not reinventing the wheel (it may already exist somewhere)

Comment: You might want to have a look at the [`countries`](https://github.com/hexorx/countries) gem.

Comment: Thanks @spickermann, good to know. Does it have any cross functionality with stripe at all?

Comment: Stripe doesn't expose a full list of country names as shown in your screenshot. The closest thing would be the `country_specs` API which lists country-specific information related to Connect: https://stripe.com/docs/api/country_specs

Comment: thanks @ttmarek that was the first place I looked, but it's good you mentioned it. I think it would be handy to include such a list in the Stripe gem, as simple [onboarding requires the developer to provide the connected user's country to Stripe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65064633/5783745), so the developer at the very least will need an array of 2 character country codes, but will probably want to display them as the full country name. Having the list somewhere (or a method that subsets a list in the countries gem) would be handy to have. I wonder if someone already did this.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so there it is. Note that Mexico's commented out

```rb
stripe_connect_countries = [
  'Australia', 
  'Austria',
  'Belgium',
  'Bulgaria',
  'Canada',
  'Cyprus',
  'Czech Republic',
  'Denmark',
  'Estonia',
  'Finland',
  'France',
  'Germany',
  'Greece',
  'Hong Kong SAR China',
  'Hungary',
  'Ireland',
  'Italy',
  'Japan',
  'Latvia',
  'Lithuania',
  'Luxembourg',
  'Malta',
  # 'Mexico',     
  'Netherlands',
  'New Zealand',
  'Norway',
  'Poland',
  'Portugal',
  'Romania',
  'Singapore',
  'Slovakia',
  'Slovenia',
  'Spain',
  'Sweden',
  'Switzerland',
  'United Kingdom',
  'United States'
]
```

Also note, that the `country` argument to Stripe functions typically wants a two-character alphanumeric country code (such as 'US', 'EG', or 'GB'). [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2#Officially_assigned_code_elements) is a full list of country codes

Since it turns out these countries are user-friendly, but Stripe functions require the 2 character codes, here's a useful function providing a hash mapping countries to codes (again, Mexico commented out)

```rb
def stripe_connect_countries

  {'Australia': 'AU', 
    'Austria': 'AT',
    'Belgium': 'BE',
    'Bulgaria': 'BG',
    'Canada': 'CA',
    'Cyprus': 'CY',
    'Czech Republic': 'CZ',
    'Denmark': 'DK',
    'Estonia': 'EE',
    'Finland': 'FI',
    'France': 'FR',
    'Germany': 'DE',
    'Greece': 'GR',
    'Hong Kong SAR China': 'HK',
    'Hungary': 'HU',
    'Ireland': 'IE',
    'Italy': 'IT',
    'Japan': 'JP',
    'Latvia': 'LV',
    'Lithuania': 'LT',
    'Luxembourg': 'LU',
    'Malta': 'MT',
    # 'Mexico': 'MX',     
    'Netherlands': 'NL',
    'New Zealand': 'NZ',
    'Norway': 'NO',
    'Poland': 'PL',
    'Portugal': 'PT',
    'Romania': 'RO',
    'Singapore': 'SG',
    'Slovakia': 'SK',
    'Slovenia': 'SI',
    'Spain': 'ES',
    'Sweden': 'SE',
    'Switzerland': 'CH',
    'United Kingdom': 'GB',
    'United States': 'US'
  }

end
```