# Set default country for phone number field in Stripe Connect onboarding?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

This is pretty minor, but for better UX, during stripe connect onboarding, I would like the phone number field to default to the connected user's country (just like the address field does). How can I make this happen? Note that I do not have the user's phone number, so I can't provide it as a [parameter to `Account.create()`](https://stripe.com/docs/api)

#### Reproducible example

Create an new account and onboarding link

```rb
country = "US"

Stripe.api_key = Rails.application.credentials[Rails.env.to_sym][:stripe][:secret_stripe_test_key] 

account = Stripe::Account.create({
  country: country, 
  type: 'express',
  capabilities: {
    card_payments: {
      'requested': true,
    },
    transfers: {
      'requested': true,
    },
  },
  settings: {
    payouts: {
      schedule: {
        interval: "manual"
      }
    }
  }
})

account_links = Stripe::AccountLink.create({
  account: account.id,
  refresh_url: 'https://example.com/reauth',
  return_url: 'https://example.com/return',
  type: 'account_onboarding',
})
```

When visiting the onboarding link (i.e. via `account_links.url`), despite the account's country being `"US"`, the phone number defaults to Australia:

[image]

#### Question

How can I make the phone number field default to the country of the account?

#### Note

The address field *does* default to USA, as desired:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can not make stripe set country code for phone field based on country parameter you have sent. Stripe does not consider the country parameter for setting phone. If phone field is null, then it fills it automatically.